# conversion of MathematicalPI symbol names to Unicode

Tags: pdf, unicode

I am processing PDF files and wish to convert characters to Unicode as far as possible. The MathematicalPI family of character sets appear to use their own symbol names (e.g. "H11001"). By exploration I have constructed a table (for MathematicalPI-One) like:

```
    <chars>
        <char charname="H11001" codepoint16="0X2B" codepoint="43" unicodeName="PLUS"/>
        <char charname="H11002" codepoint16="0x2D" codepoint="45" unicodeName="MINUS"/>
        <char charname="H11003" codepoint16="0XD7" codepoint="215" unicodeName="MULTIPLICATION SIGN"/> 
         <char charname="H11005" codepoint16="0X3D" codepoint="61" unicodeName="EQUALS"/>
    </char>
```

Can anyone point me to an existing translation table like this (ideally for all MathematicalPI sets). [I don't want a graphical display of glyphs as that means each has to be looked up as a Unicode equivalent.]

Also there seems to be a similar symbol resource where the charnames are of the form C223 (for copyright). Any information on this will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I need something well beyond @user1808924's answer - I have already compiled by own (partial) translation table so it's certainly possible to construct one. It is possible to download and display a list of glyphs in MathematicalPI (may hundreds) and to go through the Unicode spec making equivalences (and for the majority I think there are clear equivalences). A satisfactory answer would either include a table with hundreds of equivalences or a defintive statement that this would violate Copyright of the font creator.

UPDATE: Between @minopret and @Miguel it is certainly possible to construct a mapping. The MathPi sets are well defined - a few hundred - and shapecatcher makes it easy to find the best glyphs pictorially. The mapping won't be definitive (i.e. with Adobe's stamp) but it will be worthwhile. And I suspect there will be cases where two different glyphs are essentially identical and so a visual mapping wont work - e.g. is an equilateral triangle INCREMENT or GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA?

I doubt that I personally will complete a full table - I don't know what some of the symbols mean. But I hope to produce a subset used in Scientific technical medical (STM) publishing.

@user1808924 I notice you answered this on your first day on SO. Bounty questions are normally offered (as in this case) for difficult questions where there is a definitive answer but it is difficult to find. It's not normally useful to offer opinions or guesses unless you have expert knowledge of the area.

Comment: To clarify, you're after the Adobe Mathematical Pi fonts, as opposed to the Linotype Universal Mathematical Pi fonts?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a difference! Any explanation would be valuable. But *if* there is a significant difference that I would probably prefer Adobe. It is more likely to be used in authoring tools.

Comment: I'm not sure there is, mind you, but doing a bit of research on these faces I came up with both these, obviously related, but not apparently identical. Even more confusingly, it seems that Linotype was the author of the Adobe font, at some point, but given that Linotype has renamed theirs, I can't be sure they're the same any more.

Comment: I might also add that the TeX gurus out there might already have the map you're seeking, if TeX was one of the authoring tools.

Comment: Thanks! If the TeX gurus publish it they will probably get the bounty! And I am hopeful that the two sources you quote will be largely similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best information as provided by Miguel Sousa of Adobe in his [Typography forum message](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4840079) there:

- [Mathematical Pi 1-6 PDF](https://workspaces.acrobat.com/?d=dPPRA3pgqa5RAhpZ92QVzQ) / [Mathematical Pi 1-6 InDesign IDML](https://workspaces.acrobat.com/?d=urv4Qy5WFEpQ5sCUmfmGZg)
- [Mathematical Pi Std PDF](https://workspaces.acrobat.com/?d=Meg4v9%2aJudACTW9WlMMXHw) / [Mathematical Pi Std IDML](https://workspaces.acrobat.com/?d=6nd8SkKj0m0ku4uh0ZqFuQ)

For what it's worth and to summarize information that I had added in comments on this answer, here is what I was able to find before and apart from that.

Michael Sharpe, creator of package "mathalfa" at [CTAN](http://ctan.org) and member of UCSD mathematics, has TeX definitions for Mathematical Pi in [this archive file](http://math.ucsd.edu/~msharpe/mathpiTDS.zip). I successfully guessed that the obsolete documented location at me.com has moved to his university site. The ".vf" files map the characters of Mathematical Pi to TeX math codepoints. They are binary. The mapping data is part of the dump to readable text using the tool "vftovp" that is part of TeX distributions. After performing that dump, we find that the mapped characters are:

```
mathpibb: 'hyphen-minus' 0-9 A-Z a-z
mathpical: percent 'hyphen-minus' A-Z
mathpifrak: 'hyphen-minus' 0-9 A-Z a-z
mh2s: A-Z
```

So that explains the package name "mathalfa". He took on only the task of employing the alphabetics and digits but hardly anything more. We must look at the files above for mappings for the symbols.

I think that parts of MathPi, such as the Greek letters of MathPi 1, use the same encoding as Adobe Symbol, which is documented here: http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt

When attempting to map symbols to Unicode oneself, a good way to find the Unicode point is by drawing the glyph on the screen here: http://shapecatcher.com

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This is the sort of thing I want. There doesn't seem to be very much that is easily understandable in there and I can't use it in it's present form. (the files are binary) If anyone can extract some mapping in ASCII I'd be happy to award the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for your update. In the worst case we will have to sit down with the glyph tables from MathPI (which are accessible from documents which expose the complete font info) and convert by hand. At least then others won't have to go through the same process.

Comment: Very helpful. I agree the Greek mapping looks promising (and seems to abide by Symbol Font as in Wikipedia). The Adobe mapping is very useful as it also gives a list of those characters which Adobe is likely to use. Not sure whether it solves the mathPi problem.

Comment: shapecatcher looks very useful and solves the wider problem of mapping glyphs to unicode. Shapecatcher appears to be Open source (it's on Github) and also uses public lists of glyphs. I was going to have to write something like this anyway so it may have saved me a lot of work. If nobody puts in a better answer in the next few hours then I will award the bounty.

Comment: you are right that it's a good idea to ask authoritatively where possible. The reason that StackOverflow is a good place to come initially is (a) that it might already have been done and (b) people like you know where to ask (I didnt even know that MathPi was and Adobe font.) This has all been extremely helpful and so you get the bounty. Even though it's not exactly what I asked for, much of it is even more valuable

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that there is such translation table available at all.

It looks to me that `MathematicalPI` font family is a synthetic one, which has been created *ad hoc* by selecting a subset of elements from some larger unknown set. The *raison d'être* of `MathematicalPI` font family seems to be the representation of simple algebraic operators (plus, minus, multiplication, division) and the equals sign. The charnames (ie. `H1100X`) appear to be artifacts, because they are not ordered after codepoint values (eg. the equals sign is the last one).

By looking at the available data, I can suggest that the missing `H11004` charname should correspond to the division operator. However, it is impossible to predict if it should be represented by the Unicode "solidus" character (ie. `U+002F`), "division sign" character (ie. `U+00F7`), or something else.

Comment: MathematicalPI is much better defined than you suggest. I have already gone much further than this and explored some 10 points in the set. MathematicalPI has standard glpyhs and is quite clear that H11004 corresponds to a division sign, not a solidus. It seems quite possible that someone has created a table where (say) H11004 is mapped to U+00F7 as the closest equivalent and it was this that I was asking for.

Comment: see @minopret's answer - there are certainly mappings

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I published on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4839631) site:

I could be wrong, but I don't think there's an official correspondence table.

Using the six Type 1 fonts and the OpenType font that was made out of them, I've assembled two PDFs which show all the glyphs. Next to them are the glyph names (for the Type 1 fonts) and the Unicode value(s) (for the OpenType font). If you cross reference these two PDFs, you should be able to assemble the correlation list you're looking for.

[Mathematical Pi](https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/b445ea2f-fcbb-44af-a798-fc854d8dd9b5)

Hope this helps.

Miguel

Comment: It might be good to provide the full answer here in the event that the link breaks sometime in the future.

Comment: Very useful. The problem is well defined and tractable. Some glyphs are obvious and now that shapecatcher is able to identify rarer glyphs it is a few hours' work to construct most of the mapping

Comment: BTW, while going through some old books I found a softbound book from The Monotype Corporation Limited entitled "List of mathematical characters - 'Monotype' 4-line Mathematics Series 569 & L231". There's no date on it, but I'm guessing it's from the 1970's. Many of the characters listed in this book use the names that are also used by the Type 1 fonts. These names are called Matrix Numbers. I believe Monotype is the source of these names/codes.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW my current mapping table (from reading documents created using MathPI, is:

```
<codePoint name="H9251" unicode="U+03B1" unicodeName="GREEK LOWERCASE LETTER ALPHA"/>
<codePoint name="H9252" unicode="U+03B2" unicodeName="GREEK LOWERCASE LETTER BETA"/>
<codePoint name="H9253" unicode="U+03B3" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER GAMMA"/>
<codePoint name="H9254" unicode="U+03B4" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER DELTA"/>
<codePoint name="H9255" unicode="U+03B5" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON"/>
<codePoint name="H9256" unicode="U+03B6" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER ZETA"/>
<codePoint name="H9257" unicode="U+03B7" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA"/>
<codePoint name="H9258" unicode="U+03B8" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA"/>
<codePoint name="H9259" unicode="U+03B9" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA"/>
<codePoint name="H9260" unicode="U+03BA" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER KAPPA"/>
<codePoint name="H9261" unicode="U+03BB" unicodeName="GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA"/>
<codePoint name="H9262" unicode="U+03BC" unicodeName="GREEK LOWERCASE LETTER MU"/>

<codePoint name="H11001" unicode="U+002B" decimal="43" unicodeName="PLUS"/>
<codePoint name="H11002" unicode="U+002D" decimal="45" unicodeName="MINUS"/>
<codePoint name="H11003" unicode="U+00D7" decimal="215" unicodeName="MULTIPLICATION SIGN"/> 
<codePoint name="H11005" unicode="U+003D" decimal="61" unicodeName="EQUALS"/> 
<codePoint name="H11011" unicode="U+007E" decimal="126" unicodeName="TILDE"/> 
<codePoint name="H11021" unicode="U+003C" decimal="60" unicodeName="LESS" htmlName="lt"/> 
<codePoint name="H11022" unicode="U+003E" decimal="62" unicodeName="" htmlName="gt"/> 
<codePoint name="H11032" unicode="U+0027" decimal="39" unicodeName="APOSTROPHE" htmlName="apos"/> 
<codePoint name="H11034" unicode="U+00B0" decimal="176" unicodeName="DEGREE SIGN" htmlName="deg"/> 

<codePoint name="H11554" unicode="U+00B7" decimal="183" unicodeName="MIDDLE DOT"/>
```